# How to set the size of search result in Grails Searchable plugin

Tags: grails, grails-searchable

For my application I am using Grails Searchable plugin. By default the search result size is 10 results per page. How can I can increase the search result size because I want to show all the results on one page instead of doing paginating stuff. Please advise me, Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at: http://grails.org/Searchable+Plugin+-+Methods+-+search

you have to use the result option 'every'.

```
// get all articles containing the term 'test'
def articles = Article.search(
    "test",
    [result: 'every']
)
```